# MongoDB - Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript

I tried to run a typescript [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/tree/master/imageboard) in the following way which caused following error:

```
$ mongod --dbpath /home/u/databases
$ npm install
$ tsc --sourcemap --module commonjs app.ts
$ node app.js                             
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
========================================================================================
=  Please ensure that you set the default write concern for the database by setting    =
=   one of the options                                                                 =
=                                                                                      =
=     w: (value of > -1 or the string 'majority'), where < 1 means                     =
=        no write acknowledgement                                                       =
=     journal: true/false, wait for flush to journal before acknowledgement             =
=     fsync: true/false, wait for flush to file system before acknowledgement           =
=                                                                                      =
=  For backward compatibility safe is still supported and                              =
=   allows values of [true | false | {j:true} | {w:n, wtimeout:n} | {fsync:true}]      =
=   the default value is false which means the driver receives does not                =
=   return the information of the success/error of the insert/update/remove            =
=                                                                                      =
=   ex: new Db(new Server('localhost', 27017), {safe:false})                           =
=                                                                                      =
=   http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/getLastError+Command                           =
=                                                                                      =
=  The default of no acknowledgement will change in the very near future                =
=                                                                                      =
=  This message will disappear when the default safe is set on the driver Db           =
========================================================================================

/home/u/tmp/TypeScriptSamples/imageboard/app.js:9
app.configure(function () {
    ^
TypeError: Object function (req, res, next) {
    app.handle(req, res, next);
  } has no method 'configure'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/u/tmp/TypeScriptSamples/imageboard/app.js:9:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:929:3
```

Furthermore, looking at db.ts I think `http` and `url` are missing in `package.json` file, am I right?

How is it possible to fix the above error with mongodb?

Comment: Did you try to execute `npm update` before doing it?

Answer (score 7):

in Linux operating system first remove bson folder from `node_modules` and run this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc make build-essential
```

and then restart nodejs file such as `index.js`. Hope its helpful

Answer (score 2):

I am using connect-mongo for sessions. I had the same problem and was because the version of connect-mongo generated an error with the version 4.0.x of mongoose. You could check each version of the dependencies you are using.

Answer (score 1):

> looking at db.ts I think http and url are missing in package.json file, am I right?

No. These modules are a part of core nodejs.

The source of the error is the package.json specifying minimum numbers without backward in compatible version locks. https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/imageboard/package.json#L6 I would change '>=' to be harder versions e.g. 3.x

Comment: Thank you, I removed `>=`, but when I loaded `localhost:3000` this error appeared: `TypeError: Property 'engine' of object #<View> is not a function
    at View.render (/home/u/tmp/TypeScriptSamples/imageboard/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:75:8)
...`